# shift roster - Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am trying to prepare a shift roster for 24/7 support (weekly rotational shift). But I am not able to create a roster as per the below requirement. Can you please help to add 8 resources for 24/7 support in the attached xls file? Thanks in advance.

Number of Resources: 8
working hours: 9 hours for one resource
Number of shifts : 3 (morning, afternoon & Night)
Number of resources in each shift: 2
During the weekend (Sat & Sun): one resource in each shift instead of 2

[template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwBK4.jpg)

Comment: You can do this with the Solver.

Comment: can you make a few sample of your data here instead of image and sample of your result